# Primefaces menubar menuitem Width

Tags: primefaces

I am having trouble with the menuitem
:(

**Wanted to include a pic, but wasnt allowed**
So question is stupid without it

I can't seem to change the width of the drop down menu,
I have included a style in my head and a width attrib in
each menuitem, but they have made no difference:

```
<style>
ui-menu .ui-menu-parent .ui-menu-child
{
    width: 400px; /* exagerated !! */
}
</style>
```

When the menu item is higlighted, the selection bar is the correct width !

Any Clues ???, here is an example menubar

```
<p:menubar>
    <p:submenu label="Menu 1"
        style="text-align: left;">

        <p:menuitem ajax="false" 
                    action="/Page1"
                    value="Page 1" 
                    style="width: 350px;"/>

        <p:menuitem ajax="false" 
                    action="/too_long_page"
                    value="Some really long menu text that is far too long"
                    style="width: 350px;" />

        <p:menuitem ajax="false" 
                    action="/too_long_page"
                    value="Some really long menu text that is far too long"
                    style="width: 350px;" />

    </p:submenu>
    <p:menuitem ajax="false" 
                action="/Page2"
                value="Page 2" />
</p:menubar>
```

Answer (score 17):

if you want the width follow your content, use this

```
ul.ui-menu-child {
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: On Primefaces 6.2, this work correclty for pretty all my menus. Except for <p:submenu> that contains items with icons that are displayed on 2 lines. For all these submenus, I have fixed the width explicitely. I vote up :-)

Answer (score 6):

use this:

```
<style>    
       ul.ui-menu-child
        {
            white-space: nowrap;
            width: 290px !important;
        }
</style>
```

Only change the pixels that you need :) and dropdown width of menu will change.

Answer (score 3):

```
 <style>
     ul.ui-menu-child{
     width: 250px !important;
        }
 </style>
```

temporary solution.

Answer (score 2):

This should help:

```
.ui-menu {
    min-width: 350px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however, tried all variations of this, I think it's further down, I even tried important!, if I could upload a screen shot, you would see what the problem is,
or try recreating it using very long text as on or more of your menu items.

Comment: It works for me. Try removing all other references to ui-menu-whatever from your css sources. I've also changed the definition to min-width as width also changes the p:menubar's width.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a shot, when I get the chance, unfortunately I have that horrible thing called "work" to do :-}

Answer (score 1):

The style element within the head is likely being overridden by the Primefaces stylesheets that are placed after it on the page markup.  If you view the page throug Firebug you will likely notice that the custom style is in fact being overridden by the Primefaces stylesheets.

On that note, your stylesheet is correct because using Firebug I was able to increase the menu width by forcing this style on the DOM element.

Try placing this style tag within the body instead and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: mmm interesting username, anyway, will try, thanks, see comments above

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, thank you, thank you, finally an answer
here it is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Prime Faces Examples - ??</title>
        <style>
            ul.ui-menu-child
            {
                width: 460px !important;
            }
        </style>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>  
            <p:menubar>
                <p:submenu label="Menu 1"
                           style="text-align: left;">

                    <p:menuitem ajax="false" 
                                action="/Page1"
                                value="Page 1" 
                                style="width: 450px;"/>

                    <p:menuitem ajax="false" 
                                action="/too_long_page"
                                value="Some really long menu text that is far too long"
                                style="width: 450px;" />

                    <p:menuitem ajax="false" 
                                action="/too_long_page"
                                value="Some really long menu text that is far too long"
                                style="width: 450px;" />

                </p:submenu>
                <p:menuitem ajax="false" 
                            action="/Page2"
                            value="Page 2" />
            </p:menubar>
        </h:form>  
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Other alternative

```
ul.ui-menu-child {
    width: auto !important;
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to obtain a submenu width depending on the max content even with icons in place one could use the following.

(jsf):

```
<p:menubar styleClass="yourClass">
```

By providing an additional css class you can easily toggle between the default behavior and your custom settings.

CSS:

```
.ui-menu.ui-menubar.yourClass .ui-menuitem-text {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.ui-menu.ui-menubar.yourClass .ui-menu-child {
    width: auto;
    padding-right: 34px;
}
.ui-menu.ui-menubar.yourClass .ui-menu-child .ui-menuitem {
    width: calc(100% + 30px);
}
```

maybe you have to adjust the pixels used in the calculation depending on your icon size but the used values working fine for my theme.

[image]