# How do I prevent Primefaces from wrapping between submenu text and triangle icon?

Tags: css, primefaces

When a sub menu label gets too long, Primefaces puts the right-pointing triangle on the next line:

[image]

How can I make Primefaces put the triangle on the same line, as it does with the short sub menu items?

I saw [Primefaces menubar menuitem Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882722/primefaces-menubar-menuitem-width) but when I added those CSS rules, the behavior did not change.

In particular, changing the `a.ui-menuitem-link`'s CSS that holds both the link text and the triangle icon, didn't help:

```
a.ui-menuitem-link {
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: auto !important;
}
```

This is probably some simple CSS thing, but I just don't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for me was to remove the `!important` from the CSS rule; that way other rules could override it, in this case the regular Primefaces styles.

Answer (score 1):

menuitem style affects just the item within the menu, and does not act on the overall menu that opens.

If you are using p:menuButton you can use the **menuStyleClass** attribute:

- **Name**: menuStyleClass
- **Default**: null
- **Type**: String
- **Description**: Style class of the overlay menu element.

A simple example:

in your css file:

```
.superWide
{
    width:      300px;
    min-width:  300px;
    max-width:  300px;
}
```

menuButton:

```
<p:menuButton value="menu" menuStyleClass="superWide">
    ...
```

results may vary with other primefaces menu types.

Comment: I guess that might work for some cases, I'm just allergic to hard-coded pixel values.